# Buscar o valor do ID usando preg_match_all em PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

Recebo uma string em PHP e preciso buscar os valores dos IDs, pode ser 1, como podem ser 100 ID's, como fazer? Tentei algo assim:

```
$texto = 'Nome1 <span id="indicado-b">Camila</span> Nome2 <span id="indicado-c">Walter</span>';
preg_match_all('/<span id="indicado-(.*)">/',$texto, $match);
print_r($match);
```

O valor que preciso receber é **b** e **c**, que são os valores dos ID, mas não está retornando isso, recebo:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Camila Nome2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => b">Camila Nome2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar a classe [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) (PHP 5+) e trabalhar com a string como HTML, ficando mais fácil manipular os elementos como HTML, e usar um laço `foreach` nos `spans` pegando os atributos `id` e usar `preg_match` para obter as letras após o hífen

```
<?
$texto = 'Nome1 <span id="indicado-b">Camila</span> Nome2 <span id="indicado-c">Walter</span>';

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($texto);
$spans = $d->getElementsByTagName("span");

foreach($spans as $id){
   preg_match('/indicado-(.+)/', $id->getAttribute('id'), $match);
   $ids[] = $match[1];
}

var_dump($ids);
?>
```

No final você terá uma array `$ids` com as letras que deseja.